# how to decrypt saml token objectguid for SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I am working ADFS SAML authentication after successful authentication I get the SAML claims but I don't know how to decrypt token objectguid which has value in some encrypted format (may in base64 with some encrypted key).
I guess may need to provide certificate thumbprint but not sure how to do that, could anybody help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer thanks.. [base64 to guid to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172134/base64-to-guid-to-base64)

var d =new Guid(System.Convert.FromBase64String("XXXXXXXXXXXX=="));