# Base64 mongodb - [js] Error: invalid base64

Tags: mongodb, powershell, base64

I have a function that takes as input a Hex `MD5` Hash, converts it to `Base64` and then issues a `find` against a Mongo database.

The string `$Base64MD5` in the snippet below contains: `lxCzLiriwm0tPHW+r0wawQ==`
which checks out as a valid `Base64`.

When added to the `mongo` command string and executed:

```
$Hashhit = mongo --host $connectionString --eval @'
db.Media.findOne
(
{ 'Batches.Hashes.Hash': BinData(0, '$Base64MD5') }
)
'@
```

I get:

```
<MongoDBValidate>   MongoDB shell version v4.0.15 connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27018/
local?gssapiServiceName=mongodb Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("acec5f08-d0b4-438c
-9782-bce72b585a22") } MongoDB server version: 4.0.4 2020-02-03T08:58:27.235+0000 E QUERY  

  [js] Error: invalid base64 :  @(shell eval):3:26
```

Its somewhat perplexing. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: can you share collection

Comment: maybe the `+` and `=` characters cause problems, try using base64url encoding instead

Comment: Hi Mahesh. I am calling the mongodb shell directly and not using the Mdbc cmdlets.

Comment: Running the script with the + and = chars as is works perfectly. For example db.Media.findOne
(
{'Batches.Hashes.Hash': BinData(0,'3Y7x7oWSxNnWM15GrpmS/Mr2P34=')  }
)

Comment: Just to check - I looked at Base64URL replaced '+' and '/' with '-' and '_' and get the same error response. If I omit the '=' padding it also give the same error response.

Comment: Can you show us the part where you are converting the Hex MD5 Hash into Base64? It may have something to do with [endianess](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/). See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172134/base64-to-guid-to-base64)

Comment: function Naive-Convert-HashToByteArray {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ( [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)] [String] $String )
    $String -split '([A-F0-9]{2})' | foreach-object { if ($_) {[System.Convert]::ToByte($_,16)}} }

function ConvertTo-Base64 {
$global:FHaB = Naive-Convert-HashToByteArray($HexHash)

$global:Base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($global:FHaB)

Comment: Sorry not the neatest comment added above

Comment: you can [edit] your question to add code or other details.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a here-string with single quotes in your `mongo` command line, which means it's not interpolating the  `$Base64MD5` variable - it's literally embedding the string `$Base64MD5` as the second parameter to `BinData`.

Compare this example with a single quote here-string (`@' ... '@`):

```bsh
PS> $aaa = "myfile.txt"
PS> x$ = notepad @'
>> $aaa
>> '@
```

which launches notepad and shows the error `Cannot find the $aaa.txt file.`

vs this with double quotes (`@" ... "@`)

```bsh
PS> $aaa = "myfile.txt"
PS> x$ = notepad @"
>> $aaa
>> "@
```

which shows the error `Cannot find the myfile.txt file.` instead.

Try changing your here-string delimiter to double-quotes - i.e.:

```bsh
$Hashhit = mongo --host $connectionString --eval @"
db.Media.findOne
(
{ 'Batches.Hashes.Hash': BinData(0, '$Base64MD5') }
)
"@
```

and see if that works...

Comment: Yes that sure did - many thanks for taking the time to help me out. Much appreciated